# JDialog appearing without any content

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, event-dispatch-thread

So i've been having this problem with making my `JDialog` appear. I'm aware it's not a new question but i still can't quite grasp the concept of EDT, Concurrency in `Swing`. I'm hoping someone can explain this in an easy manner(or point me to some well explained resource) how does this work and how exactly would i include that in my code to make the `JDialog` work.

Here's the resource i was reading regarding Concurrency http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

and here's my code:

```
public class TestView {

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing Radio Dialogs");
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
String[] folderNames = { "Java", "Ruby", "C++", "HTML" };

JRadioButton r11 = new JRadioButton(folderNames[0]);
JRadioButton r22 = new JRadioButton(folderNames[1]);
JRadioButton r33 = new JRadioButton(folderNames[2]);
JRadioButton r44 = new JRadioButton(folderNames[3]);

public TestView() {

    frame.add(mainPanel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    mainPanel.add(button);
    button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    mainPanel.add(r11);
    mainPanel.add(r22);
    mainPanel.add(r33);
    mainPanel.add(r44);

}

class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getSource() == button) {

            createPopup();

            System.out.println("Button clicked!");

        }

    }

}

public void createPopup() {

    JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    JPanel dialogPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
    dialogPanel.setSize(150, 150);      
    JRadioButton r1 = new JRadioButton("Ruby");
    JRadioButton r2 = new JRadioButton("Java");
    JRadioButton r3 = new JRadioButton("C++");
    JRadioButton r4 = new JRadioButton("HTML");
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(r1);
    group.add(r2);
    group.add(r3);
    group.add(r4);
    dialogPanel.add(r1);
    dialogPanel.add(r2);
    dialogPanel.add(r3);
    dialogPanel.add(r4);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    System.out.println("Popup created!");

}
}
```

I browsed through similar questions on different forums, but i'm still not quite grasping the concept. I'd appreciate any sort of feedback on this matter and my code.

Comment: What is the problem? It is working on my Mac PC.

Comment: JDialog pops up but without the content (JRadioButtons) and with the minimum sized window. Im on PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problems with concurrency or the dispatch thread, you just forgot to add `dialogPanel` to the `dialog`.

```
public void createPopup() {
    //...
    dialog.add(dialogPanel);
    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setVisible();
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, That was indeed the issue. However, the popup window still starts almost minimized despite setting the dialogPanel size. I tried setting dialog size (which i should do to begin with) but i'm getting the same result. Do you perhaps know the cause of this problem?
EDIT: Fixed thanks to @camickr comment.

Comment: The `dialog.pack()` in the sample code in my answer fixed that. You must have added only one of the 2 new lines. :)

Answer (score 1):

Note, when you create your frame you are adding components to the mainPanel AFTER the frame is visible. By default all components have a zero size so there is nothing to paint. I would be surprised if your code works.

The order of your code should be:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.add(...);
frame.add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible();
```

All the components should be added to the panel before making the frame visible. The pack() will invoke the layout manager which is responsible for determining the size/location of the components on the panel.

The setVisible(true) should be the last statement.

Comment: That fixed all the issues regarding the size of my window. Thanks a lot for your insight.

Comment: The default component size isn't zero; it depends on the layout manager, the component UI, explicit settings, etc. Still adding static components prior to `setVisible(true)` is the right way to go. Just to be clear though, it *is* possible to add components after a container is visible as long as you validate. See the java.awt.Container#addImpl() docs.

Comment: I should be more precise about the component's default size. Even though the component's default *size* is zero, the *preferred size* used by most layout managers isn't. So there would be something to paint for layout managers that respect the preferred size.

Comment: @KevinCondon  ` it is possible to add components after a container is visible as long as you validate.` - use revalidate() with Swing. `So there would be something to paint for layout managers that respect the preferred size` only if the layout manager has been invoked, which was the point of my comment. The layout manager was not invoked because the components were added after the frame was made visible.

Comment: @camickr Agreed. Well, one odd thing - the frame did display properly with the OP's original code when I ran it. It was only the popup that wasn't working. I would have predicted with you that the frame would not have properly rendered content, but it did. Something done during the Swing/AWT screen render process did validate the containers, but I don't know what. It's certainly not a behavior I'd ever rely on.